# IndexOf function

Tags: c#

I have this below code which will fetch loggedin UserID

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
        //networkID=User.
        string strName = p.Identity.Name;
        int start;
        start = strName.IndexOf("\") + 1 ; 

  strName = strName.Substring(start, strName.Length - start);
```

But start = strName.IndexOf("\") + 1 ; throwing out error saying Newline in constant. The logged in username I get is domainName\username and I want to use only username. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `IndexOf(@"\")` or `IndexOf("\\")`.

Answer (score 5):

`\` is an escape character - you must use either `"\\"` or `@"\"` to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [escape your backslashes](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx) by doubling them:

```
start = strName.IndexOf("\\") + 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backslash is escaping your last quote.  use a double backslash to escape your backslash.

```
start = strName.IndexOf("\\") + 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character. You either need to escape it with another `\` or use verbatim string literals:

```
start = strName.IndexOf("\\") + 1 ;
```

Or:

```
start = strName.IndexOf(@"\") + 1 ;
```